# Измерить скорость интернет соединения пользователя

Tags: javascript, php

Каким образом возможно измерить скорость интернет соединения пользователя?
Заставить скачать файл, не выход...

Comment: Вам все равно нужно что то прокачивать через канал, хоть рандомные данные

Comment: Никак, скорость она такая, существует только в момент скачивания и в каждый момент времени разная. Это как спидометр на машине, пока вы не едите, вы не можете знать, на какой скорости вы едите :)